# eigen: Subtracting a scalar from a 3D vector c++

Tags: c++, eigen

The problem is in camera.cpp
   t * n(2) = (x(2) - optical_center);
problem is 24:22: Invalid operands to binary expression ('Scalar' (aka 'double') and 'Eigen::Vector3d' (aka 'Matrix'))
I understand may be it is related to vector scaler subtratcion, can anyone please help?

```
const void Camera_::t_from_point(const Eigen::Vector3d &n,
                                      Eigen::Vector3d &x ){
    double t;
    x(2) = 1;
    t* n(2) = (x(2) - optical_center); // this line is the problem
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your question in unreadable, but from the title, I guess you are looking for:

```
Vector3f v;
v << 1,2,3;
v.array() -= 1;
// v == [0 1 2]
```

See Eigen's [array world](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).